# How to send user details collected from different activities during signup to the final activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-volley

I am busy adding a signup feature to my app and I have 4 activities which I use to collect the user's information. The activities are supposed to collect the details input by the user and send them all to the final activity where they will be sent to the database.

The first activity asks users to choose whether they want to use their email or phone number to sign up.

The second activity asks users to choose their username and password.

The third activity asks the user to add more personal details as well as to add a profile picture to their account.

The final activity asks the users to input their geographic details and then sends all the information sent from the other activities to the database.

The problem I am facing is that if i use Intents, i need to send data from activity to activity. Which is giving me a lot of errors, how can I the information collected in each activity to the final one and then send them all in one go.

Comment: Among other things, you can create a model object `user` and then pass that object from activity to activity, while updating it each time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Singleton design pattern which preserves single object between all activities.

For example:

```
public class SignUpSingleton {
private int emailOrPhone;

private String username;
private String password;

private String firstName;
private String lastName;

private String country;
private String city;
//remaining fields here

private static SignUpSingleton instance = new SignUpSingleton();

private SignUpSingleton(){}

public static SignUpSingleton getInstance(){
    return instance;
}


public int getEmailOrPhone() {
    return emailOrPhone;
}

public void setEmailOrPhone(int emailOrPhone) {
    this.emailOrPhone = emailOrPhone;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getCountry() {
    return country;
}

public void setCountry(String country) {
    this.country = country;
}

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}
```

}

In the first activity:

```
        SignUpSingleton.getInstance().setEmailOrPhone(1); //1 or 2
```

In the second activity:

```
        SignUpSingleton.getInstance().setUsername("Tom");
        SignUpSingleton.getInstance().setPassword("pass");
```

And so on for third and forth.

In the last activity you can send all data to the database at once, e.g:

```
storeInDb(
            SignUpSingleton.getInstance().getEmailOrPhone(),
            SignUpSingleton.getInstance().getUsername(),
            SignUpSingleton.getInstance().getPassword(),
            SignUpSingleton.getInstance().getFirstName(),
            SignUpSingleton.getInstance().getLastName(),
            //remaining params here

    );
```

Assuming you have a method called `storeInDb` or alike, and inside it the database code.

Comment: Thank you, that answered my question perfectly :D

Answer (score 1):

Please use my code i am sure to help you

i am giving demo class of three activity

is this your FirstActivity

```
public class FirstActivity extends Activity
{
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);      
    }
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();

        //put this code as per your requirement
        // i am just giving idea

        Intent i=new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("name","Riyaz Parasara");
        i.putExtra("email","riyazparasara@gmail.com");
        i.putExtra("phone","+918955094537");
        i.putExtra("country","india");
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

is this your secondActivity

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity
{
    private String name,email,phone,county;

    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);  

        //this is first activity data
        //you can get firstactivity data in second activity 
        //and store data into varialbles

         name=getIntent().getStringExtra("name");   
         email=getIntent().getStringExtra("email");
         phone=getIntent().getStringExtra("phone");
         country=getIntent().getStringExtra("country");

    }
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();

        //put this code as per your requirement
        // i am just giving idea

        Intent i=new Intent(this,ThirdActivity.class);

        //this is first activity data put in intent

        i.putExtra("name",name);
        i.putExtra("email",email);
        i.putExtra("phone",phone);
        i.putExtra("country",country);


        //this is second activity data you also put on this intent

        i.putExtra("sex","male");
        i.putExtra("age","24");
        i.putExtra("city","jaipur");

        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

is this your FinalActivity please read code comments carefully

```
public class FinalActivity extends Activity
{
    private String name,email,phone,county,sex,age,city;

    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);  

        //this is first activity data and second activity data
        //you can get firstactivity and secondactivity data in Final activity 
        //and store data into varialbles

         name=getIntent().getStringExtra("name");   
         email=getIntent().getStringExtra("email");
         phone=getIntent().getStringExtra("phone");
         country=getIntent().getStringExtra("country");

         sex=getIntent().getStringExtra("sex"); 
         age=getIntent().getStringExtra("age");
         city=getIntent().getStringExtra("city");


        //all data are in instance variable please use this data whenever



    }
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();

        //if you need to send data another activity 
        //please repeat again previous steps as per your requirement


    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!!

My app takes place in the onCreate() section. Users insert their details into EditText boxes and then they are stored when the "Next" button is clicked, how would I incorporate your code to work in the onCreate()?

I hope this makes sense, if not I will explain further :)

Comment: i am adding comments please add intent onClick while button pressing

Comment: i am just giving demo please add intent code in onClick() method

Answer (score 0):

Use a POJO class User, for instance, which will have all the attributes(name, email, location to name a few) you're likely be needing to complete the Sign up process.

Pass and update this User class object in every activity. The User class needs to implement Serializable or Percelable in order to be passable through Intent though.

```
public class User implements Serilizable {

private String usename;
private String email;
private Location location;
// Other attributes

// Getters and Setters


}
```